# is this image button reproducible in CSS cross browser?

Tags: css, image, button, cross-browser, submit

Hi CSS savvies out there!

I got this image that I use as a submit button

[image: search]

Since the website will be multilingual, I don't want to create different images for each language.. so I want to make it a CSS cross-browser button.

Is it possible? and how should I go since this is an slightly difficult button.

Thanx a lot :)

Comment: @Radu detailed the best way to do it. That said, I wouldn't recommend trying to reproduce this effect "cross-browser" (which is a subjective term). I would focus on making it look good in modern browsers that support CSS3, and have a decent looking (degradable) experience for lesser browsers that do not support CSS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *possible*, but not easy. You could break it up into the following images:

1. Top left corner
2. Top right corner
3. Bottom left corner
4. Bottom right corner
5. Left border
6. Right border
7. Top border
8. Bottom border
9. Center

This is called the "9-patch" method. However, your bottom border contains a non-tilable glare. You could also add 2 more patches to this:

1. Bottom left stretchable pixels between the bottom left corner and the bottom border
2. Bottom right stretchable pixels between the bottom right corner and the bottom border

You can then wrap these elements in an `inline-block` div and use that as the button. There's also a new [`border-image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#border-images) property that you can use with CSS3, but it doesn't have good support yet.

You can embed the font with `@font-face`.

Comment: with this method; i need to use java script to submit the form -when the div is clicked.
this rises other problems with js non enabled browsers

Comment: @numediaweb, that's right. The best approach, as Moses says, would be to have something looking good for the majority of your target audience and gracefully degrade for the minority. As for JavaScript, if 99% of the users _do_ have JavaScript enabled, then it makes sense to use a JavaScript approach by default and provide a regular (and perhaps colored) submit button for the rest 1%.

Comment: I'm following your method. so far I created the button an the jQuery that submits it,and good news; it works on Firefox v5.. Tested in Chrome v12 and it misses the image.. Tested in IE8 and button not showing up.. i got to find a way make IE & co. swallow the border-image property :)

Comment: Since I have only few buttons on the website, I decided to stick with images instead of CSS3, 9-patch divs, jquery etc.. this allows me to avoid lot of headache with browser compatibility and keep my design clean :)

Comment: @numediaweb, good choice. Do take a look at the technique called [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/158-css-sprites/) to see how you can optimize serving these images.

Comment: Thanx Radu..but even the sprite technique won't give me what I needed because of the nature of this button.. and to be honest; I don't want that much trouble with browser compatiblity,it is the end result that counts not the way to achieve it.. no!?

Comment: @numediaweb, indeed. The idea with sprites though is not directly related to this... It's just grouping more images into one so you can reduce overhead. More of an optimization thing than anything else.

Comment: thanx radu fopr your help and support!

Answer (score 1):

Create an image for button purple background (without text) and use it as a background for `<input type='button' id='button_search' value='search'>`.

CSS

```
input#button_search{
  background-image:url("imagename.png"); /*your image*/
  width:170px; /*width of your image*/
  height:43px; /*height of your image*/
  border:none;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

The text 'Search' or in another language can be set as `value` of input.

Comment: the problem with this method is you can't use it with long words :(

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is save the border of the button as an image(the bit with the shadow/emboss effect) and then set the middle part as a gradient in CSS. Not only with you be able to put whatever text you so wish, but the gradient effect is able to applied for most browsers. Check [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) out to generate your gradients.

**Update:** Instead of making an image for each, why not just do a sprite? Make the outside part of the image a background, then have another large image that contains the middle part(the part with "search") and just change the background position on that sprite for each different language.

Answer (score 1):

Create an image without having the text, give an `id` to your `input type="button"` and a `value="search"`

e.g.

if your button is

```
<input type="button" id="yourButtonId" value="search" />
```

Using css select your button with `id` like, `input#yourButtonId` and use your image as a background of this button without repeating and proper positioning, giving the button a width and height property exactly as your button background image then style the text as your desire with css rules.

Comment: some as above:  
the problem with this method is you can't use it with long words :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS3 however not all browsers support that standard yet, but you could use a fallback so when the browser doesn't support CSS3 you can display a simple purple background for the button.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-browser is very subjective and relative. If you mean modern browsers and don't count IE, sure. IF you count IE 1-9, Netscape Navigator 4.1, old Gecko browsers, etc., then of course not. First decide who your demographic is, and then decide if it's worth it to you to accommodate the minority with an image fallback or not.

Comment: Cross-browser is; sine by default winxp is ie6, and since IE is a piece of ... I should start from IE6 upwards.
For the other browsers; Firefox, Chrome, Safari and co..it's okay since they easily get updated.. the only problem is with Microsoft browsers